# Nhibernate many to many xml

Tags: c#, sql, orm, nhibernate

I want to make a many to many relation in Nhibernate, but I am stuck at the moment, I have 3 sql tables, student class and studentclassrelation and I have written 2 classes in c#

```
class Student
{ 

        public virtual int StudentID { get; set; }

        public virtual string name { get; set; }

        public virtual IList<Class> Classes { get; set; }

        public virtual void AddClass(Class Classer) {

            Classes.Add(Classer);
        }

    }
    '''

class Class
{
    
        public virtual int ClassID { get; set; }

        public virtual string name { get; set; }
        public virtual string teacher { get; set; }
       
        public virtual List<Student> students { get; set; }

        public virtual void AddStudent(Student stud) {
            students.Add(stud);
         
        }
}
```

my xml file look like this, the other is the same

```xml
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateTutorialPart1"
                   namespace="NHibernateTutorialPart1">

    <class name="Student">

        <id name="StudentID" column="StudentID" >
        
        </id>

        <property name="name" />
        
<bag name ="Classes" table="ClassStudentRelation" cascade ="all" inverse ="true" >
    <key column="ClassID"></key>
    <many-to-many class="Class"> </many-to-many>
    </bag>
    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

and in my main I created this objects

```
Student sven= new Student {StudentID=7,  name = "sven" };
Class Ai = new Class {ClassID=7, name = "AI", teacher = "lauer" };

List<Class> tmp = new List<Class>();
List<Student> save = new List<Student>();

save.Add(sven);
tmp.Add(Ai);

Student sven2= new Student { StudentID = 62, name = "sven2",Classes=tmp };
Class Ai2 = new Class { ClassID = 62, name = "AI2", teacher = "lauer2",students=save };

mySession.Save(sven2);
mySession.Save(Ai2);
mySession.Transaction.Commit();
```

if I commit without the sven and ai without the list i am able to commit the information in the right sql tabel, but i want to commit ai2 and sven2 with a list of the other that i get the information into 3 tables but that doesen work somebody know how to fix it.
the error ist a missmatch with

```
NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericBag and NHibernate.Collection.Generic.PersistentGenericList
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the Classes bag mapping. Assuming that the ClassStudentRelation junction table has StudentID and ClassID foreign keys. The mapping should be :

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
               assembly="NHibernateTutorialPart1"
               namespace="NHibernateTutorialPart1">

<class name="Student">

    <id name="StudentID" column="StudentID" >        
    </id>

    <property name="name" />
    
<bag name="Classes" table="ClassStudentRelation" cascade="all" inverse="false">
    <key column="StudentID"></key>
    <many-to-many class="Class" column="ClassID" />
    </bag>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

The inverse attribute should be set to false because the collection is responsible to manage the relationship.

The mapping for the Class object would be something like :

```
<class name="Class">

    <id name="ClassID" column="ClassID" >        
    </id>

    <property name="name" />
    
<bag name="Students" table="ClassStudentRelation" cascade="all" inverse="false">
    <key column="ClassID"></key>
    <many-to-many class="Student" column="StudentID" />
    </bag>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Also you cannot overwrite the collections in your nhibernate entities. The collections should be initialized ASAP and then you can use the AddClass/AddStudent methods.

```
class Student
{ 
...
public virtual IList<Class> Classes { get; set; } = new List<Class>();
...
}

Student sven2= new Student { StudentID = 62, name = "sven2" };
sven2.AddClass(Ai);
Ai.AddStudent(sven2);
mySession.Save(sven2);
mySession.Save(Ai);
```